# Old package name isn't being changed on refactor package name for Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I made a hundred copies of a project and went through a refactoring of the project name to try and change them to make them unique. I, however, only managed to change it in the Android Manifest and the rest of the app... but in the emulator and on the google play store, it still has the origial package name. What is going on. I followed guidethroughs on how to refactor the package name and that should have fixed it... but it still doesnt go through. What am I missing here?

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jakegosskuehn.crystalmaiden" >
```

top of all java files:

```
 package com.jakegosskuehn.crystalmaiden;
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized what went wrong when I checked the build.gradle script for the module:app.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.jakegosskuehn.***OLD_PACKAGE_NAME***"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Just renaming the applicationId to be the same as everything else should fix the problems in the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want change package name,this is a simple way:

1.Create a flavors.Step:
  Right click you project->'Open Module Settings'->Choice 'app'->Choce tab 'Flavors'->Then you can see a 'defaultConfig'.Cretae a new ,give a name you like.

2.Then you will see a new flavos in you 'build.gradle',like this:

```
    productFlavors {
    myflavor {
    }
}
```

you can add new config lick this:

```
productFlavors {
    myflavor {
        applicationId "cn.imengya.newpackagename"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

3.Open the 'Gradle project',then your can find the some new task with you new flavors.Then new task can build .apk with new packagename.